# Android: Playing two sounds one after the other

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play two sound items, one after the other

```
MediaPlayer mp        = null;

 protected void produceErrorSound(int index) {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
        }


        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, index);

        mp.start();
    }


public void correctAnswerAndNext(){
    produceErrorSound(R.raw.right1) ;
    produceErrorSound(R.raw.right1) ;
}
```

but only second sound is produced.
is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see any wait mechanism in your code.

You can use an [onCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) to receive a callback when your first MediaPlayer has finished playback. At that point you can start the second MediaPlayer.

An alternative way in Jellybean (and later versions) is to use the audio chaining functionality (i.e. [setNextMediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29)) to automatically start another MediaPlayer as soon as the current one has finished playing. Something like this (I've omitted the calls to `setDataSource` etc for brevity):

```
mediaPlayer1.prepare();
mediaPlayer2.prepare();   
mediaPlayer1.start();
mediaPlayer1.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer2);
```